# Why my Zapcode is with low resolution?

Tags: video, after-effects

I developed a Zapcode and [follow the tactics to have a video with good resolution](https://creator.zapcode.it/support/3/what-video-formats-are-supported/), I've done a video in MP4 and FLV, both rendered in the After Effects, but remains at low resolution. [Here is my Zapcode](http://cl.ly/image/1e0t2o1x0G0s). What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you post a copy of what the video you are uploading looks like?

Comment: Yes, [FLV](http://cl.ly/3r0x2x1Q3p0q) and [MP4](http://cl.ly/1C2a0W3I0a0o).

Answer (score 1):

The Zapcode Creator compresses the video further in order to reduce download size of the video and so that it will run in an AR camera view on lower end devices. This means that it will be lower resolution than what you have uploaded.

If you like you can email us at support@zappar.com and we can take a look at your Zapcode and video to see if there's any specific suggestions we can give.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, send an email.